# Google API Authenticate using Service Account

Tags: python, http, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm currently using the Google's client however I'm struggling to find any documentation relating to how to use it so I'm looking to authenticate using the Service Account using HTTP however i'm struggling to find any documentation on it.

Can anyone help me find the documentation for either the python client or making an http call to google to authenticate the service account?

Comment: Can I ask you about `authenticate using the Service Account using HTTP`?

Comment: @Tanaike sure you can